# Name of phenomenon when you place a word(s) between 'will' and the verb?

Tags: future

When you split 'will' away from the verb that it is putting into the future tense, what do you call it?

For example:

> We *will* **then** *analyse* this information.

This is similar to splitting the infinitive, or [tmesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis) - I guess.

Comment: I don't know a name other than tmesis (which in my experience is usually used when a single word is divided, as "abso-bloody-lutely"). There is no reason to regard "will analyse" as a element which should stay together - it is only called a "future tense" because other languages have future tenses - so I don't think there's much call for a word for putting something else in between.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought tmesis was when a word was split; didn't realize it was also when phrasal verbs are interrupted. I'm honestly a bit disappointed that the latter could also be called tmesis...

Answer (score 3):

Words like "will", "do," and "have" are called ***auxiliaries*** or ***auxiliary verbs***. Words like "should,", "would," "could," and "must" are called ***modals*** or ***modal verbs***.

Both auxiliaries and modals combine with other verbs and can be ***split*** away from them. The phenomenon is called ***verb splitting***, ***auxiliary splitting***, or ***modal splitting***.

[Here](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/01/syntax) is a blog which uses the phrase "split verb" to refer to the more general phenomenon, encompassing split infinitives, split auxiliaries, and split modals.

Answer (score -3):

An example:

> We will not eat a banana.

*not* is not part of the verb, so you are splitting apart *will* and *eat*.

Comment: This does not answer the question. -1

Comment: @ColinFine Why not?

Comment: Ashley asked for a name for the phenomenon. You have merely given another example of it.